# Saving data to firebase realtime database according to the user (web app)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is the user]
[image: THIS is my data]

I would like to save my data like a photo shown below:

[image: I would like to save my data like a photo shown below]
this is my code

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Apartment/');

var address = document.getElementById("addr").value;

var uids = firebase.database().ref().child('Apartment').push().key;

var data = {
    address: address
}

var updates = {};
updates['/Apartment/' + uids] = data;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: The "I would like to save my data like a photo shown below" is the image link

Comment: What did you try already? If you haven't tried anything, it is unlikely that we'll do a better job explaining than the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) or than what you'd learn from taking the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).

Comment: first I've created a reference then save my data in that child using push().key

Comment: Is there any easy way to communicate with you? so that i can send you my code

Comment: That's now how Stack Overflow works. If you have problems making your code work, read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add that to your question by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53805005/edit) link under it. That way others can help too.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Frank

Comment: There are now three screenshots from three different parts of your database. Is that really the minimum data needed for your question? Also note that I don't fully understand what the problem is with the code you shared. Does it not update the database? Does it update the wrong place in the data?

Comment: there is no problem in my code when it comes to saving but my problem is i dont know how to associate the data to the user who is log in. I am so sorry sir Frank I am beginner only thank you for your understanding

Comment: I have a huge of data, I also try so many time to solve my problem but I dont get the right thing taht i want

Comment: There is no need to be sorry. But you have to try and explain the minimum-but-complete details of what you're asking. None of the code you shared deals with a user, so it's hard to understand where you're trying to use that. If you're using Firebase Authentication, see the [documentation on how to determine the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)